# Using filter() rather than map() to modify an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning javascript from a course on Educative. I have a very simple question on the difference between filter() and map(). I am given a list of student objects, each containing a name, sex, and an array of grades, and I am asked to return a list of female students containing their name, sex, and average grade.
(Link: https://www.educative.io/courses/the-complete-javascript-course-build-a-real-world-app-from-scratch/qVlyoEpxYEk)

The input is:

```
const students = [
  {
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];
```

and the expected output is:

```
[ { name: 'Anna', sex: 'f', grades: 4 },
  { name: 'Martha', sex: 'f', grades: 3.625 } ]
```

The given solution is as follows. I understand everything except for the last line. Why are we using filter() rather than map() to apply avgGrade to the array of female students? I thought filter() was supposed to return only array elements that meet the conditions specified in a function.

Also, why does using filter(students,femaleList).map(avgGrade) not work?

```
function studentResult(students) {
  
const femaleList = student => student.sex === "f";
const avgGrade = arr => arr.grades = arr.grades.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.grades.length;
const filter = (student, func) => student.filter(func);
const result = filter(filter(students,femaleList),avgGrade);
  
return result;
}
```

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

function studentResult(students) {
  
const femaleList = student => student.sex === "f";
const avgGrade = arr => arr.grades = arr.grades.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.grades.length;
const filter = (student, func) => student.filter(func);
const result = filter(filter(students,femaleList),avgGrade);
  
return result;
}

console.log(studentResult(students));
```

Comment: Just an FYI seeing how you said you're just starting to learn, this code is written in a poor, confusing way and shouldn't be "aspired to".

Comment: is this really the code from the course? ask your money back.

Comment: @webduvet - OMG, I thought it was encountered in the wild, this is code used to teach people? 

Answer (score 4):

That code is really poor. The filter functions don't need to be scoped, and it's written in a purposely confusing way. If I found the dev that wrote that, I'd have a word with him/her.

EDIT: Just re-read the post, I can't believe this code is supposed to try to teach people JS. Well, once you figure it out, OP, make sure you never write anything like it on the job.

FYI, It should be a `filter` then a `map` - you first filter to get only the female students, then map to average grade:

```js
function averageGrade(grades) {
 return grades.reduce((acc,g) => acc+g,0)/grades.length
}


function studentResult(students) {
 return students

    // get only the female students
    .filter(student => student.sex === 'f')

    // compute the average grade
    .map(student => ({
        ...student,
        grades: averageGrade(student.grades)
    }));
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer!:) Do you have any suggestions about other resources for learning javascript? I realized from people's comments that I might not be learning from the best resource.

Answer (score 3):

You are right in your question. The `filter(   ,avgGrade)` works only because none of the averages turn out to be zero. If that were the case, the corresponding (female) students would have been excluded.

Secondly, `avgGrade` is not a pure function: it mutates the `grades` property. It is not best practice to use such impure function as callback for `filter`, nor for `map`.

So, yes, this should have been a `map`, not a `filter`, but not with the impure `avgGrade`:

`filter(students,femaleList).map(avgGrade)` will not work, because `avgGrade` does not return a student, but a grade. So `.map` would need a different callback.

Below `avgGrade` is corrected to be a pure function, returning a new student kind of object.

To stick with the coding style that is used with `filter`, it also defines `map` as a function:

```js
const students = [{
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  }, {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  }, {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  }, {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

function studentResult(students) {
  const femaleList = student => student.sex === "f";
  const avgGrade = arr => ({...arr, grades: arr.grades.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.grades.length});
  const filter = (student, func) => student.filter(func);
  const map = (student, func) => student.map(func);
  const result = map(filter(students, femaleList), avgGrade);
  return result;
}

console.log(studentResult(students));
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array.filter()` and `Array.map()` do different things.

`Array.filter(block)` iterates through all of the elements and returns a new array of elements which, when passed into `block`, return true.

`Array.map(block)` iterates through all of the elements and returns a new array of elements which are the *return value* of `block`.

`filter(students,femaleList).map(avgGrade)` does not work because `avgGrade` implicitly just returns the average grade, so the resulting array just contains the average grades themselves. To fix this, all you'd have to do is return the input element after calculating the average.

Like so:

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

function studentResult(students) {
  
const femaleList = student => student.sex === "f";
const avgGrade = arr => {
  arr.grades = arr.grades.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.grades.length;
  return arr;
}
const filter = (student, func) => student.filter(func);
const result = filter(students,femaleList).map(avgGrade);
  
return result;
}

console.log(studentResult(students));
```

You could also set result to just be the filter, and then do the map as is **but not assign it to result**.

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

function studentResult(students) {
  
const femaleList = student => student.sex === "f";
const avgGrade = arr => arr.grades = arr.grades.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.grades.length;
const filter = (student, func) => student.filter(func);
const result = filter(students,femaleList);
result.map(avgGrade);
  
return result;
}

console.log(studentResult(students));
```

Answer (score 2):

neither `filter` nor `map` should be used to modify anything.
Here is how it should look like with some explanation in the comments.

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

const expected = [
  { name: 'Anna', sex: 'f', grades: 4 },
  { name: 'Martha', sex: 'f', grades: 3.625 }
]

// filter fn for female
const isFemale = (item) => item.sex === 'f';

// make average of numeric array
const makeAverage = (arr) =>
  arr.length > 0 // check for empty array we do not want divide by 0
    ? arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0) / arr.length
    : 0;

// mapping fn to make average grades
// this will not ammend original
// provided that there is no more nesting
// if there are any other nested objects cloning the object would be
// safer option.
const withAverageGrade = (student) => ({
  ...student,
  grades: makeAverage(student.grades)
})

const result = students
  .filter(isFemale)
  .map(withAverageGrade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter and map differ slightly. Filter is more for searching, "filtering" an array while map is more for changing "manipulating" an array. An example could be yours, the last line is filtering the array to get the females, including average grade, from the list of students. If you were to somehow replace that with map, the objective would change to modifying the grades or modifying the gender.

Here's a better, more suited explanation than mine: https://medium.com/@c.mansour/the-difference-between-the-filter-and-map-array-methods-in-javascript-f8164f65fa5e.

However, I will provide a few examples.

```
const dog = filter(dogList, isMale);
```

The code above would create an array of dogs that are male.

```
const addOne = numberList.map((v) => v + 1);
```

The code above would put the numberList array into addOne, while increasing the values by one per index.

I hope I could help you understand better, and if you have anymore questions just comment below!